# Parameter validation failure when passing datetime into report viewer

Tags: c#, asp.net, exception, reporting-services, parameters

So I'm attempting to view a remote ssrs report using a reportviewer control in asp. The report takes three parameters - an nvarchar and two datetimes. Passing the single nvarchar worked fine until I added the two datetimes, at which point I get the following error. so there must be some issue with that. I consistently get the dreaded error:

```
    Parameter validation failed. It is not possible to provide valid values for all    parameters. (rsParameterError)
```

This, despite passing in values for all three parameters. I guessed it was an issue with the / characters in the date string, so I tried url encoding those, to no avail. I can confirm this report does run from the reporting services, but I cannot seem to pass the parameter values in correctly from my code. Suggestions?

My code is as follows

```
    string firstdate = datepicker.Value;
    string enddate = datepicker2.Value;

    firstdate = HttpUtility.UrlEncode(firstdate);
     enddate = HttpUtility.UrlEncode(enddate);

    ReportParameter[] parm = new ReportParameter[3];
    parm[0] = new ReportParameter("store_name", DropDownList1.SelectedValue);
    parm[1] = new ReportParameter("mindate",firstdate);
    parm[2] = new ReportParameter("maxdate", enddate);



    ReportViewer1.ServerReport.ReportPath = "<REDACTED>";
    ReportViewer1.ServerReport.ReportServerUrl = new Uri("http://<REDACTED>/ReportServer");
    ReportViewer1.ServerReport.ReportServerCredentials = new ReportServerCredentials("<REDACTED>", "<REDACTED>", "");
    ReportViewer1.ProcessingMode = ProcessingMode.Remote;
    ReportViewer1.ServerReport.SetParameters(parm);
    ReportViewer1.ServerReport.Refresh();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out the .rdl file was broken, but I'm not sure how. Completely recreating the report seems to have fixed the issue.